# I am getting invalid number of output values for dcc.Store

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have two different `dcc.Store` components to store results of two queries in the dashboard.

```
html.Div([dcc.Store(id='memory-store')]),  
html.Div([dcc.Store(id='mem-store2-ov')]),
```

The callback function for the first `dcc.Store` `'memory-store'` component works fine. I run a query, store it to a `pd.DataFrame` and return `df.to_dict('records')`.

I repeat this process for the second `dcc.Store` component (but with a different query) but when I try to return the resulting `DataFrame` to the `dcc.Store` `'mem-store2-ov'` I get error message

> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: Invalid number of output values for ..mem-store2-ov.data...
>   Expected 1 got 8896

What is causing this? For the first `dcc.Store`, I sometimes get different number of values in the `DataFrame` too, but I do not get this error message.

Comment: This sounds like a bug in your code, nothing related to dash.  Specifically, python is interpreting your return "value" as an array of values, not a single object.  Can you provide more code?